# How to use screen capture UI standalone, to edit existing images?

Tags: screen-capture

When doing screen capture in MacOS, you get a pop up in bottom right corner. If you click on it, you get UI for simple edits on this image. Nevertheless, I love it! It looks like this

[image: Screen capture editor]

But how can I use it for existing files?

Comment: What mac and what version of the system software are you running?

Comment: @jmh, Based on the description and screenshot, gadelat is running **macOS Catalina** and the feature is the **Show Floating Thumbnail** when taking a screen shot. I know this is **macOS Catalina** because **Apple** removed the _Rotate Right_ button, which was in **macOS Mojave**, for this feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, since **macOS Mojave**, when taking a *screen shot* a *floating thumbnail* briefly appears in the lower right-hand corner of the **Desktop**, which one can click on to edit the *screen shot*.

The editor which appears, because by default **Show Floating Thumbnail** is checked in the **Options** for taking a *screen shot*, can be used on an *image file* or *screen shot* afterwards by selecting the *image file* in **Finder** and then *right-click* on the *image* and select: **Quick Actions** > **Markup**

You can also, after selecting the *image file*, press the *spacebar* to bring up a *quicklook view* and click the **Markup** button.

Answer (score -1):

I do a screen capture using Shift-Option-4 and I don't get any UI for this. You can open the file in Preview and it has some simple editing tools. You can adjust the exposure, for example, by using the Adjust Color selection under the Tools menu. There are other options as well. The menu bar you show looks very much like the menu bar in Preview.